# How do I confirm cmus is using alsa?

Tags: alsa, cmus

I've searched the net and came up with the configuration below. but I don't think my cmus install is using alsa.

How do I know? Well, I installed strawberry and have configured it to use alsa. If I play youtube on the browser and then try playing on strawberry , I'll get a message that goes like "playback device is busy right now". I have to stop the Youtube playback first before strawberry starts playing music.

If I do same with cmus, I can hear sound from **both** cmus and Youtube.

Any ideas? Thanks

**this is my configuration**

```
[my-user@fedora ~]$ cat /etc/asound.conf 
#
# Place your global alsa-lib configuration here...
#
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.ctl.card 1

[my-user@fedora ~]$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [Dell monitor]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Series [Mini-i Series], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

[my-user@fedora ~]$ cat ~/.config/cmus/rc 
set output_plugin=alsa
set dsp.alsa.device=default
set mixer.alsa.device=default
set mixer.alsa.channel=Master
```

Comment: Because there is no mixer setting as part of your global alsa conf but there is one as part of your cmus settings ? BTW are you using Alsa directly ? ( I mean no pulse/pipewire & al ) In case you are using Alsa directly… I can post some answer.

Comment: @MC68020 pipewire and alsa were installed by default on fedora 37. I'm guessing YouTube/browser/cmus is playing sound via pipewire by default.